# How to remove the ‘VPN is not configured’ icon from the menu bar on macOS?

Tags: macos, vpn, menu-bar

[image: screenshot of menu bar]

I don’t know when it appears.

Could you tell me how to remove or add the icon?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In that menu, click 'Open Network Preferences ...'
and in the next dialog, uncheck the option 'Show VPN status in menu bar'.

[image]

Comment: If you don't have this checkbox, click on + to add a fake VPN, then you can see and uncheck this box, and remove this fake VPN.

Comment: This worked for me, thank you. I already knew how to remove it via command-drag, but I wanted to know why it was showing in my menu and also why I couldn't find the setting to disable it.

Answer (score 17):

You can usually (but not always) remove a menulet icon by holding down the Command key and dragging it off.

Comment: Command-drag is correct, this *is* the first-party macOS VPN

Comment: Here's how it looks: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2GqCo5NmK1s

Comment: it is correct way to do worked on 10.15.7